# What is stored in the ready queue for a process?

Tags: operating-system, scheduler, task-queue

I try to use hardware to speed up the scheduling and dispatching. 
Therefore i need to know what exactly is in the ready queue in order to figure out whether using hardware can indeed help and by how much.

In all OS literature, it just mentions scheduler fetches process and put into ready queue.
And i have some knowledge about process, like virtual address space, executable code, PID and so on.
But i just can't connect them together. I don't think each time, scheduler will store all these information in the ready queue.

So can somebody help? What is exactly stored in the ready queue? Like how many bytes of data, what are they? If it is system-dependent, can you give me at least one example for one system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ready queues stores the processes which can be executed in the processor when given an opportunity i.e. the processes which are not waiting for any sort of I/O operations, etc to complete before they can be executed.

As far as h/w for increased scheduling and dispatching is concerned,
I feel increasing the main memory capacity can help substantially.
Increasing main memory will result in less swap in/ swap out of memory blocks between secondary and primary memory and hence will ultimately result in less thrashing which will increase the performance very much.